# How can I control the rqt_plot x-axis scale?

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using `rqt_plot` to plot movement of the turtle in `turtlesim`. Steps:

1. `$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`
2. `$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot`
3. In the "Topic" box of the rqt_plot window, type "/turtle1/pose"

In the window, rqt_plot is scrolling too fast. The width of my window represents 1 second. How do I change the x-axis scale to show more data and scroll more slowly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203894/how-can-i-control-the-rqt_plot-x-axis-scale?/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't remember exactly, but there's some combination of right- or middle-click, the CTRL key and dragging which zooms the X and Y axes.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clancy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20877/clancy/) on 2015-04-23**:
It's right-click and drag on 14.04 and Indigo.